# SQL DateTime convert to Time String

Tags: sql

I have table Proccesses that consist of Date Time Field.

```
Proccesses ( Id as int , RunDate as DateTime)
```

I need to run Distinct by RunDate as Time Without seconds

For Example

```
ID        RunDate 
1         2011-12-13 12:36:26.483
2         2011-12-12 12:37:22.421
3         2011-12-11 12:36:44.421
```

I need to receive in output

```
Output
12:36
12:37
```

I tried to use DatePart but did not manage

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(hour, RunDate) + ':' + DATENAME(minute, RunDate) AS Output...
```

Comment: The problem if I have in hour part 8 I need to convert to "08" . How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server

select CAST(DATEPART(hour, RunDate) as varchar) + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(minute, RunDate) as varchar)

Comment: he needs a `distinct` selection.

Comment: Why CAST(DATEPART)? DATENAME returns a string.

Comment: The problem if I have in hour part 8 I need to convert to "08" . How can I do it ?

Comment: you can add each part to a "0" string, then take the rightmost 2 characters ie Right("0" + Cast(Datepart(hour, RunDate) as varchar),2)

Comment: @BrianDriscoll that's right; I always forget about DATENAME.  Trap of familiarity I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try

- for hours: `DATEPART(hh, RunDate)`
- for minutes: `DATEPART(mi, RunDate)`

Comment: The problem if I have in hour part 8 I need to convert to "08" . How can I do it ?

Answer (score -1):

```
select CONVERT(varchar,RunDate,103) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(5),RunDate,108)
```

(in Sql Server)